# Huge memory consumption rendering geojson files

Tags: qgis, geojson, ubuntu

I have a road network graph saved in geojson - size about 150MB. When I load it to QGIS as the only layer, QGIS (which uses about 140MB at this point) starts allocating memory up to about 8GB. Another memory (GBs) is then allocated when zooming in/out or moving the view quickly hitting all available RAM (about 12GB). Is this normal QGIS behavior or is it a bug/memory leak?

EDIT: tested on Windows on the same data - memory usage does not exceeded 2GB and decreased after full load of the layer. So it looks like the problem is linux/ubuntu specific.

Comment: It does not feel quite right even GeoJSON is a suboptimal format for big datasets because it does not support spatial or any other kind of indexes. I suggest to make a comparison by converting data into GeoPackage or shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

This is a GDAL issue - I understand it will be improved with the upcoming GDAL 2.3 release.

Comment: Are you sure that this will be addressed? And what is the released date for version 2.3?

Comment: Is there a GDAL ticket about the issue?