# How much process memory is needed for ogr2ogr to process a GeoJSON file? -

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, memory

I am trying to evaluate how many resources ogr2ogr needs to process a GeoJSON file; there's a concern that it's using much more memory than we would expect.  All we are doing is converting a GeoJSON file, filled with point features, to create another GeoJSON file - to validate the file, and convert the coordinate system to our target CRS.   When I run it under Ubuntu Linux, and run the TOP command, the process seems to take about 134000 KB  of virtual memory, regardless of the file size.  However, the amount of buff/cache used seems to vary with the size of the file being converted.  How much memory should a process have to run ogr2ogr?

Comment: I can't imagine why this would matter. If you were processing 300-million vertex geometries, then you might start to notice RAM use, but for trivial data sources, the nominal heap is likely large enough to never need extension.

Comment: If you hit memory issues, you may use other intermediate formats than GeoJSON. Did you try to use GeoJSONSeq https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojsonseq.html ? It avoids the pain to deal with GeoJSON in memory. The bigger the GeoJSON, the more memory it consumes. It's a long standing issue for the format e.g https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270372/huge-memory-consumption-rendering-geojson-files

Comment: @Vince - I'm just looking for explanations; perhaps the real issue is competing uses of memory that leave little behind for ogr2ogr.

Comment: @ThomasG77 - We really don't have a choice, as we are trying to consume geojson from "arbitrary" sources.  So - each feature might not be on its own line.  But it's a good idea.

Comment: But that's not how modern computers work. Thanks to swap, all processes have access to all the RAM. Apps based on large shared libraries grab all the RAM they need to load at initial execution, and allocate and deallocate blocks in the heap for actual execution, When an allocation request can't meet the need, then the heap is expanded (but never released), until there is no more heap to give.  Steady-state at 134MB means the app isn't doing anything exceptional, and the process hasn't run out of memory.

Comment: @Vince - thanks for your patience, but I want to make sure I understand this.  In the top command, there's a value for "buff/cache".  If I understand it correctly, this is used to make I/O more efficient.   The memory actually needed by the application is under VIRT.  If it needs more - can it get it from buff/cache?  - it may slow I/O, but there won't be a problem with running out of memory.  In any case - if, for ogr2ogr, VIRT represents all the memory needed - we don't have a memory issue here.

Comment: In a single serial read, the file I/O buffer cache is a wasted economy. Still, this is OS overhead, not process space, and indicates the OS is twiddling its thumbs with more physical RAM than it absolutely needs, so it's caching compulsively, on the chance it could help. Applications get additional RAM from the OS  (which allocates unassigned RAM or the least recently used blocks loaned for I/O cache before leaning on swap). Without including the actual output that concerns you, it's difficult to tell, but you don't seem to have a memory issue.

Comment: @Vince - Thanks - you've helped me understand this a lot better, and eliminate a point of concern.